# Laravel insert record with one to many relationship

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have two tables car_category and vehicles and set the car Id as foreign key constraint of vehicles table's c_id.Now I want to add vehicles to vehicles table with the relationship.So I want to store the vehicle details,How 'ld I add the fk constraint to my controller?
I've set the relationship between tables like,
In Car model,

```
class car extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = [];
    protected $table = 'car_category';

    public function vehicles()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Vehicle');
    }
}
```

Vehicle Model,

```
class Vehicle extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = [];
    protected $table = 'vehicles';

    public function cars()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Car');
    }
}
```

And store vehicle details like,

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'vehicle_no' => 'required',
        'vehicle_company' => 'required',
        'vehicle_category' => 'required',
        'vehicle_type' => 'required',
        'vehicle_model' => 'required',
        'vehicle_capacity' => 'required',
        'vehicle_color' => 'required',
        'c_cid' => '',
    ]);

    Vehicle::create($request->all());
            return redirect()->route('vehicles.index')
                 ->with('success','Vehicle details stored successfully');
}
```

How to pass the fk constraint value?Can anybody help me?

Comment: whether you want to pass the id of newly inserted vehicle ?

Comment: I want to store the car category 's id(foreign key) in vehicle table .

Comment: for the simple way.. You can have the car category id in a hidden field and pass it to store function and save..

Comment: I want to code the blade file like this ?`<div class="col-md-6">
     
{{ Form::label('Vehicle', 'Vehicle ') }}
  @foreach($car as $cars)
     <select name="c_id" class="form-control">
   
         <option value="{{ $cars}}">Mini</option>
@endforeach
</select>
</div>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the car field in you form, you can get the ID while saving the vehicle

```
    <div class="col-md-6"> 
        <select name="c_id" class="form-control"> 
        @foreach($car as $cars) 
            <option value="{{ $cars->id }}">{{ $cars->Name }}</option> 
        @endforeach </select> 
    </div>
```

here you can get the value in

```
public function store(Request $request) {
    // here you can get the value
    $request->c_id;
}
```

Comment: It directs to the same page without store into db,`          {!! Form::open(array('class' => 'form-horizontal','route' => 'vehicles.store','method'=>'POST')) !!}
`